# Temporary tmp files created by Inno Setup in destination directory while installing

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup

One of my customers reported that my app installer creates a temp file like `is-XXXXX.tmp` in the `{app}` directory, which are identified by anti-virus app as malware. The temp file would only live for a very short time, so I can't make a copy of it. My customer ask me to send him a copy of the temp file to make sure there is no harmful code inside it. Is there any method to copy this temp file out on installation? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Inno Setup is extracting files to their destination folders, it always does that first by storing them to the file names like `is-XXXXX.tmp`. Only then, it renames them to their actual file names.

So all those files are actually the files that your customer has in the destination folder once the installation completes.

Comment: I've got it! Thanks a lot!