# How to prevent Inno Setup create files in TEMP?

Tags: inno-setup

I create a setup file with Inno Setup.

But some Anti-Virus software pause my setup and warn that my setup want to create files in TEMP folder.

I search around, and apparently, some virus loves to create files in TEMP folder as their first step to takeover the whole system drive. So some AV just assume that a software who create files in TEMP is most likely a virus.

Then I try finding out how to prevent Inno Setup creating files in TEMP folder with no luck.

So here I am. Is it possible to prevent Inno setup create files in TEMP folder?

Comment: Preventing use of your temp folder seems like a pretty odd way to defend your system.. sure viruses might use this resource but then don't all programs? Not sure this is the right problem you should try to solve if virus threat mitigation is your goal but maybe your system is pretty locked down!!

Comment: The temp folder is tprovided by the operating systek for software applications to use. So your anti-virus software would not make such bold statements surely. The chances are that you have not acquired a digital code signing certificate and signed your datafiles and installer.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Seem about right. Just one thing, a code signing certification is a little expensive for me. Is there a cheaper one for personal developers?

Comment: Why would it be cheaper for *"personal developers"*? You pay for costs of validating your identity. Imo, those costs are actually higher for anonymous *"personal developers"* than for registered corporations.

Comment: I have certain customers (perhaps with above average security requirements) who also complain about this TEMP folder usage, and my app & the installer are signed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Temporary tmp files created by Inno Setup in destination directory while installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62319162/temporary-tmp-files-created-by-inno-setup-in-destination-directory-while-install)